# Is there a way to change scrollview focus programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

In Swift, is there a way to change scrollview focus programatically?  For example, in one of my scrollviews when a user is scrolling, after the scroll has gone past a certain distance I want the scroll to stop scrolling and to immediately scroll a tableview instead.  I want this to all happen in the same motion/swipe, so I need to automatically shift the focus from the scrollview to the tableview using code.  Is this possible?

Comment: It will never be as smooth as you might expect. Consider changing the layout to a `UITableView`. Using a combination of table view cells and table view header, a lot of functionality can be replicated.

Answer (score 0):

Using Rikh's comment, I was able to solve this using a UITableView with multiple sections and custom UITableView headers. I can use the viewForHeaderInSection method to create a custom floating header which is exactly what I need and it scrolls much more smoothly.